# After importing variable from view.py into. No dropdown appearing in forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am using Django forms in in forms I need a variable from views.py named `'layer_id'`. So I get it like

```
   self.form = labelModelForm(layer_id=self.layer.id)
```

and used in forms.py like

```
class labelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Labels_tool_
    def __init__(self, *args , **kwargs):
        layer_id = kwargs['layer_id']
        apn= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Field.objects.filter(layer=layer_id).values_list('name', flat=True) ,empty_label="(Choose field)")
```

So now when I run program no dropdown list appear. Where I am wrong ? As layer_id I am getting is correct in form in view.py

```
My View.py file is 
 def ImportLabelView(self):
    urlItems =self.request.path.split('/')
    i = urlItems.index('layers')
    self.form = labelModelForm(layer_id=self.layer.id)
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        self.layer = Layer.objects.filter(id=urlItems[i + 1],map=self.map.id).first()
        layerid= self.layer.id
        labmapid=self.map.id
        OwnerName = self.request.POST.get('owner_name')
        MailingAddrOne = self.request.POST.get('mailing_addr_One')
        mailingaddrTwo = self.request.POST.get('mailing_addr_Two')
        ApN = self.request.POST.get('apn')
        situsaddrTwo = self.request.POST.get('situs_addr_Two')
        situsaddrOne = self.request.POST.get('situs_addr_One')
        if Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels=labmapid ,layer_id_labels=layerid).exists():
            Labels_tool_.apn = Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels = labmapid , layer_id_labels = layerid).update(apn=ApN)
            Labels_tool_.owner_name = Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels=labmapid, layer_id_labels=layerid).update(owner_name=OwnerName)
            Labels_tool_.mailing_addr_One = Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels=labmapid,
                                                                     layer_id_labels=layerid).update(mailing_addr_One=MailingAddrOne)
            Labels_tool_.mailing_addr_Two = Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels=labmapid,
                                                                     layer_id_labels=layerid).update(mailing_addr_Two=mailingaddrTwo)
            Labels_tool_.situs_addr_One = Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels=labmapid, layer_id_labels=layerid).update(situs_addr_One=situsaddrOne)
            Labels_tool_.situs_addr_Two = Labels_tool_.objects.filter(map_id_labels=labmapid, layer_id_labels=layerid).update(situs_addr_Two=situsaddrTwo)
        else:
            labels_tool = Labels_tool_()
            labels_tool.apn             = self.request.POST.get('apn')
            labels_tool.owner_name      = self.request.POST.get('owner_name')
            labels_tool.mailing_addr_One= self.request.POST.get('mailing_addr_One')
            labels_tool.mailing_addr_Two= self.request.POST.get('mailing_addr_Two')
            labels_tool.situs_addr_One  = self.request.POST.get('situs_addr_One')
            labels_tool.situs_addr_Two  = self.request.POST.get('situs_addr_Two')
            labels_tool.map_id_labels   = self.map.id
            labels_tool.layer_id_labels  = self.layer.id
            labels_tool.save()
            # self.form = self.layer.form(self.request.POST)

        return self.redirect('mapport.maps.layers.importlabel', self.map.id, self.layer.id)
    return self.render('mapport/maps/layers/Labels_detail.html')
```

And template file is

```
<form action="" method="post" id="label_form">{% csrf_token %}
 <div id="field1"><p id="apn_text">APN: </p>   {{ form.apn}}</div>
```

Models are like

```
class pdftabel_tool_(models.Model):

   apn = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
```

Now where I am making mistake that value from view.py is correct but not dropdown showing ?

Comment: from the form __init__ i can see you havent used layered_id anywhere, so what are you actually taking it for?

Comment: @Exprator sorry forget to write in querystring I have updated. kindly check

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `self.fields`, not `self.initial`.

You should define the field in the normal way at class level, then modify the queryset in the init method.

```
class labelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    apn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Field.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        layer_id = kwargs.pop('layer_id', None)
        super(labelModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['apn'].queryset = Field.objects.filter(layer=layer_id)
```

Comment: still I am getting this error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layer_id'"

Comment: Please show the full view and the full traceback, in an update to your question.

Comment: i uploaded full view